# Non-Linear Ordinary Differential Equation in Fluid Dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, fluid-dynamics

So while trying to model the physics of a rocket shot from the ground through the atmosphere, I came up with a second-order Non-Linear ODE of the form:

$$
\ddot y + \dot y^2 e^y = f(t)
$$

This is simplified, of course, but I have been searching and cannot determine a solution or if there even IS an analytic solution. Of course, maybe from my short description of the problem you already see that I am taking the wrong approach entirely; if so, please direct me to the right line of thinking.

So in summary: Is there an analytic solution to this equation? If so, what is it? If not, how should I approach this problem given certain initial values to get a numeric solution?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Would you describe how you came up with this equation? It's very interesting.

Comment: I will write up how I got to this point once I get the chance. I have been very busy recently so I haven't gotten the chance yet. Rest assured, I will get to it when I can, hopefully this weekend.